# Getting more than one jquery dropdown widget to function on one page

Tags: jquery, html, widget

Okay so on this web page there are 3 drop down menu widgets I want all of them to work obviously. I know there is much else wrong with the website but this is my specific question.

https://comp105ithaca.com/~mshek1/Final%20Project/travels.html

I thought that would be the easiest way for you guys to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have 2 main problems with this function.

**1)**

IDs should **always** be unique. Change `id="toggle-open"` to `class="toggle-open"`. Then select width `$(".toggle-open")` instead of `$("#toggle-open")`.

**2)**

You aren't opening and closing a specific box, you are selecting all of them at once. You can do something like this:

```
$(".toggle-open").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.toggle-close').show();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').show();
});
```

`$(this)` will make sure that you only target the elements related to the button you pressed, not all elements with `class="toggle-open"`.

`$(this).parent().find('ul')` will look for ul contained in the parent element of the button you pressed. Not all ul elements.